# NSPredicate for inner key in array of dictonary

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nspredicate

i have an array of dictionay in the following format

```
    [
 {
      "student": {
        "id": "1",

        "studentUserDetail": {
          "firstName": "Bonny",
          "lastName": "Roby"  
        }
    }

 },

 {
      "student": {
        "id": "1",

        "studentUserDetail": {
          "firstName": "Bonny",
          "lastName": "Kety"  
        }
    }

 },

 {
      "student": {
        "id": "1",

        "studentUserDetail": {
          "firstName": "Arther",
          "lastName": "Fone"  
        }
    }

 },

]
```

In the above array i need to filter all elements containing a serachKey (eg Bonny) in the inside key student.StudentUserDetails.firstName . How can i filter using NSPredicate

Comment: At least google...already many answers are there

Comment: already accepted long back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSPredicate *filter =  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"student.studentUserDetail.firstName CONTAINS[cd] %@ ", searchString];
```

worked perfectly for me

Answer (score 5):

```
NSString *name = @"Bonny";
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                    @"student.studentUserDetail.firstName == %@", name];     
NSArray *arr = [self.anArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];

NSLog(@"Bonny found at : %@", arr);
```

Edit:

If you want to search based on a pattern, then use:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                    @"student.studentUserDetail.firstName beginswith[cd] %@", name];
```

Comment: Actually `SELF.` can be omitted.

Comment: @vadian: Yes, agree. But I have a bad habit to use SELF with predicate :p But since you asked, I am removing it.

Comment: this was my initial predicate  but my requirement was "i need to filter all elements containing a serachKey" as mentioned in the question

Comment: @HashimMH: So whats the difference, even I am passing the searchKey as an NSString that can be changed at runtime. Or I am not getting your full requirement.

Comment: the difference is if the search key is "Bo" (didnt type the word completely, still typing the search key) the filtered array is empty and when the search key become "Bonny" i will get two elements in the filtered array. The confusion is because i didnt explain the context. actually i have a tableview with all those names displayed and there is a text field to search. So when i type on the textfield it should filter based on the current text in the searchText field

Comment: @HashimMH: so you want to search based on pattern? See the edit in answer

Answer (score 2):

```
NSArray *array = @[
                  @{
                     @"student": @{
                             @"id": @"1",
                             @"studentUserDetail": @{
                                     @"firstName": @"Bonny",
                                     @"lastName": @"Roby"
                         }
                     }
                     },
                  @{@"student": @{
                            @"id": @"1",
                            @"studentUserDetail": @{
                                    @"firstName": @"Bonny",
                                    @"lastName": @"Kety"
                                }
                            }
                  },
                  @{
                     @"student": @{@"id": @"1",
                                   @"studentUserDetail": @{
                                           @"firstName": @"Arther",
                                           @"lastName": @"Fone"
                                           }
                                   }
                  }];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(student.studentUserDetail.firstName) == %@", @"Bonny"];
NSArray *newArray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```