# Search in array with NSPredicate

Tags: ios, nspredicate

I have an `NSArray` with item is ItemModel (id, type, status,UserModel,...) and UserModel include: name, type.

I want to search an item in array with key is name of UserModel using `NSPredicate`. How do I do that?

Comment: check my answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34441282/nspredicate-for-inner-key-in-array-of-dictonary/34441592#34441592

Comment: Swift or Objective-C?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya  worked perfectly. Thanks so much

Comment: @NguyenHoan: Then please upvote the linked answer, that helps others to recognize which is the best & perfect answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
arraySearch = [ItemModel1, ItemModel2, ItemModel3, ItemModel4];
NSString *textToSearch = @"Anything you want to search";


NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name like %@",textToSearch]; 
// name is the attribute of the model, for other attributes use other attribute names there.
//Basically this code means creating a query where the array will be searched which contains the textToSearch characters.  

NSArray *result = [arraySearch filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
//your result will be returned in the array.
```

For Getting exact results try this

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@",textToSearch];
```

Comment: Thank you, but in my case it is :  let resultPredicate : NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "userModel.name contains[c] %@", key)